# How to add null date values by storedprocedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a string value `name`  that I stored like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? (object)DBNull.Value : name;
```

And I have a `DateTime` value  `date`. How can I store this date value like the above methode. My date value datatype is date. I tried like this

```
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@fromdate", SqlDbType.date).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromdate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : fromdate;
```

what I should add insted of `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.
My stored procedure code

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbo_sample]
 (
 @name varchar (50),
 @Fromdate date
 )
```

Comment: I don't see any `date` in your code. And you declare your column type as `VarChar`.

Comment: @Soner Gönül, Sir, the above methode I shown for a sample. the same way I want to insert null date value. What changes I should make to store null date value on the above sample methode?

Comment: You should post your stored procedure code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, a datetime has always a value. So, you have to test against the default value, not null

```
if (fromdate != default(DateTime))
{
    parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter {
            ParameterName = "@Fromdate",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
            Value = fromdate});

}
else
{
    parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter {
            ParameterName = "@Fromdate",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
            Value = null});
}
```

but if you handle a variable with nodate, you should use DateTime? and use nullable !

Here is what I use in production and a handy helper method :

```
public static SqlParameter CreateParam(
    string paramName,
    object value,
    SqlDbType sqlDbType)
{
    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter(paramName, sqlDbType)
    {
        Value = value ?? DBNull.Value,
    };
    return p;
}
```

and its use :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(Helpers.CreateParam(
    "@Fromdate",
    fromdate.HasValue ? fromdate.Value : null,
    SqlDbType.DateTime));
```

Comment: Please, @Amit use this post instead of the edit one. I have not enough reputation to comment edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different data type. The same as in your database target column.

either

> **DateTime**. Date and time data ranging in value from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999 to an accuracy of 3.33 milliseconds.

or

> **DateTime2**. Date and time data. Date value range is from January 1,1 AD through December 31, 9999 AD. Time value range is 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.9999999 with an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds.

[SqlDbType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Fromdate",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
            Value = fromdate == default(DateTime) ? fromdate : new DateTime?() });
```

Comment: Thanks FrenchW for Edit but it is still not able to pass null value as per question. Can we change from Value = fromdate == default(DateTime) ? fromdate : new DateTime?() }); to Value = fromdate == default(DateTime)? DBNull.Value  : fromdate});